# How to call a method on the GUI thread in C++/winrt

Tags: c++-winrt

When responding to an event in a textbox using C++/winrt I need to use ScrollViewer.ChangeView(). Trouble is, nothing happens when the call executes and I expect that is because at that moment the code is in the wrong thread; I have read this is the cause for lack of visible results from ChangeView().  It appears that the proper course is to use CoreDispatcher.RunAsync to update the scroller on the UI thread. The example code for this is provided only in C# and managed C++, however, and it is a tricky matter to figure out how this would look in normal C++. At any rate, I am not getting it. Does anyone have an example of the proper way to call a method on the UI thread in C++/winrt? Thanks.

[UPDATE:] I have found another method that seems to work, which I will show here, though I am still interested in an answer to the above. The other method is to create an IAsyncOperation that boils down to this:

```
IAsyncOperation<bool> ScrollIt(h,v, zoom){
   co_await m_scroll_viewer.ChangeView(h,v,zoom);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about your proposed solution rather than your real issue. This is called the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you really trying to accomplish? Where is the [mcve] so that we can see, where you went wrong? There's also C++/WinRT documentation on [Events; how to author and handle them in C++/WinRT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/events-author-handle). It's also not clear, what *"managed C++"* has to do with any of this. Managed C++ has been superseded by C++/CLI, unrelated to C++/CX, which is being replaced by C++/WinRT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation entry [Concurrency and asynchronous operations with C++/WinRT: Programming with thread affinity in mind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency#programming-with-thread-affinity-in-mind) explains, how to control, which thread runs certain code. This is particularly helpful in context of asynchronous functions.

C++/WinRT provides helpers `winrt::resume_background()` and `winrt::resume_foreground()`. `co_await`-ing either one switches to the respective thread (either a background thread, or the thread associated with the dispatcher of a control).

The following code illustrates the usage:

```cpp
IAsyncOperation<bool> ScrollIt(h, v, zoom){
    co_await winrt::resume_background();
    // Do compute-bound work here.

    // Switch to the foreground thread associated with m_scroll_viewer.
    co_await winrt::resume_foreground(m_scroll_viewer.Dispatcher());
    // Execute GUI-related code
    m_scroll_viewer.ChangeView(h, v, zoom);

    // Optionally switch back to a background thread.        

    // Return an appropriate value.
    co_return {};
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but having installed the latest SDK 10.0.17666.0 VS is telling me that 'namespace "winrt" has no member "resume_foreground"' - I had thought winrt was now folded into the SDK - am I mistaken?

Comment: @user3743210: I'm using the official 10.0.17134.0 SDK. `resume_background` is defined in "winrt/base.h", and `resume_foreground` is defined in "winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h". Both are in `namespace winrt`. I do not have the 10.0.17666.0 Insider Preview SDK available, and cannot check, whether those were moved elsewhere.

Comment: Well this is certainly confusing. I downloaded the 17666 SDK because of these words in the UWP docs: "For a more general solution to updating UI, which covers cases where you're uncertain about the calling thread, you can install the Windows 10 SDK Preview Build 17661, or later. Then, you can co-await the winrt::resume_foreground function to switch to a specific foreground thread." Gives the impression that 17661 is needed in order to use resume_foreground.

Comment: @user3743210: That certainly is confusing, although `resume_foreground` should still be available in the 17666 Insider Preview SDK. Have you forgotten to `#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h>`? That's assuming that the helper struct hasn't been moved to a different file.

Comment: I changed my target back to 17134 and #included Core.h - thought I had tried including that in a previous experiment but maybe I was hallucinating - and now resume_foreground compiles. On the downside, now the app crashes at co_await appFolder.GetFolderAsync(L"folderName"), though it did fine before - but that's a different topic, I think, and next up.